# Compiler error when using the new @bind:after feature in Blazor .NET7

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Been looking at the new binding features introduced for Blazor in .NET7. [This Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) explains how to use `@bind:after` (see the paragraph starting "*To execute asynchronous logic after binding...*")

I copied the code almost verbatim, replacing the call to SearchService with a `Console.WriteLine`...

```cs
<input @bind="searchText" @bind:after="PerformSearch" />

@code {
  private string? searchText;

  private async Task PerformSearch() =>
    Console.WriteLine($"Search: {searchText}");
}
```

However, this gives a compiler error... "*Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to 'System.Action<string?>'*"

This is in a brand new Blazor server project targeting .NET7 in VS Community 2022.

Anyone any idea why I'm getting this error, and how I use this new feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue that should get fixed soon.

See [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44952) for details.

Comment: Shame, it's a great feature. Thanks for the link. I spent ages searching around, don't know why I missed that one!